# auto restart of supervisord in reboot of centos

Tags: init, supervisord

I have a service file  /etc/init.d/supervisord , which I can use to start and stop the service by issuing the command

```
sudo service supervisord start
```

Now I want to make supervisord auto start when the machine reboot, and I use

```
chkconfig --add supervisord
```

However, it returns the error

```
service supervisord does not support chkconfig
```

Thus, I want to add two line to make it work with chkconfig in order to make it restart when server reboot

```
# chkconfig: 345 99 01
# description: some startup script
```

Is there any problem?